# Sprite movement flicker LibGDX

Tags: java, animation, graphics, libgdx

I posted this question already but no one is interested in responding and i have spent over 3 days trying to solve this problem. It is really annoying. I find this question everywhere but no answer. I have tried to move a sprite in libGDX over 1000 methods bu nothing seems to work. 
I have tries vSynch while adding in render loop to +speed*delta to position. I have tried only +speed. I have tried translate and everything else bu nothing seems to stop that flickering while the image is moving. What is the proper way to "move"(animate) things in libGDX. If anyone has encountered this problem, please answer this post. I am really trying to solve this problem as i can't progress without animations... This is the base for any game and i don't really understand how other games i have seen don't have flickering while moving sprites.

Comment: are you using `glClearColor` and `glClear` before the rendering starts? You must clear the screen, otherwise the old textures will be shown and a 'flickering' effect appears.

Comment: I am using glClear and glClearColor. It's just that when the sprite is moving at the edges it is very sharp and sometimes blurry. The texture itself becomes a little blurry and if you look close it is very visible. Is this a common problem?

Comment: i think not. You have hundred ways to render. Post a example with the issue, otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: Ok i will post a link with the code source and video of the problem.     Video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/768z1eox8edpyb4/javaw%202014-05-11%2018-58-54-11.avi                                                                 Code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hms4l29j7gipq3s/MiniGame.rar

Comment: where is the "flickering", dont see that on the video example.

Comment: At the edges if you look closer and on the texture.

Comment: You can also run the project through eclipse and see that the edges are flickering and there seems to be a patter on the blue rectangle which isn't there if i just render it without moving.

Comment: i will test it later, im currently not on my computer. I know, im using eclipse too ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I really don't know how to solve this and i really appreciate your help. I looked over dozens of forums but everyone said it's because of vSynch but i enabled it and forced it in the create function and didn't have any impact. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: short question: What version are you using (libGDX, Java)?

Comment: Java 8 and libGDX 1.0.0 i just updated a few seconds ago to 1.0.1 but i don't know if that is a major update.

Comment: okay. Im working with the nightly build on my game. you can try it out.

Comment: Have check it, but i dont found any issues. I've tried to disable `GL30` and `vSync` and put the `super.render();` at the bottom. I cant reproduce your problem. I think it's possibly to your graphics-driver. Try to update it and install the newest directX.

Comment: You dont need the `FPSLogger`, you can use `Gdx.grahics.getFramesPerSecond()`. And dont print it to the console, that's create an overhead.

Comment: Okay, a little problem i've found: You reinitialize the drop each rendering process, on my computer that's not the problem but i think that takes an little flickering effect.

Comment: Here is my modified source: https://www.world-of-rpg.de/MiniGame.zip

Comment: Ok thanks for the help i tried, now that you mentioned, on other GPU and it seems it doesn't flicker anymore but it moves like it has fps drops and i looked at the drop problem, i didn't get to finish it. I will test it on other GPU's too. It seems every GPU is special :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and i can't reproduce the stutter effect. It's really smooth for me. There exists a vsync bug but it should only appear in window mode.

Comment: The conclusion is that as every person differs every GPU has some kind of personality and it will render it differently. I tested the app on 4 GPUs and every time it was different...